# How to un+1 a 301d URL without removing the 301?

Tags: 301-redirect, google-plus

I found out I Google +1d this URL `http://domainA.com/this-url/` this URL has been 301 redirected to `http://domainB.com/this-url/` in the meanwhile, now I want to undo the +1 on the 301 without going through disabling the 301. Is there a quick way to do that?

Comment: For the sake of a +1 seems a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to see and edit your plus 1s if you go here : https://profiles.google.com/me/plusones